# In VSTS, how do I add an email notification task to the build and release definitions?

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am new to VSTS Continuous Integration and configuring one of my first sets of build and release definitions.

Is there a task I can add that will allow me to notify certain team members of events such as a build failed, or a release is ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **build fail notification**, you can set on https://account.visualstudio.com/_notifications -> new -> select ***Build*** for category -> select ***A build fails*** for template -> next -> select ***other email*** for Deliver to -> add the email address and separate with semicolon (`;`) for multiple email addresses -> you can filter for a specific team project -> finish.

For **release success notification**, there is no present setting for this. You can create your extension for release success email notification. More detail, you can refer [sending email notification](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/12/19/sending-email-notification-from-vststfs-build/).

Answer (score 3):

In the latest iteration of the notification settings https://account.visualstudio.com/_notifications (where there is a single global settings page), if (like me) you don't run everything full screen:

*Check the add button isn't off the side of the screen!*